# Qt 4 Sqlite, problem with QDataWidgetMapper

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt4

I'm writing a little Symbian app and I'm having troubles with QDataWidgetMapper. This is the code:

```
void Widget::bindToData(){
    databaseManager = new DatabaseManager();
    dataMapper = new QDataWidgetMapper();
    dataMapper->setSubmitPolicy(QDataWidgetMapper::AutoSubmit);
    dataMapper->setModel(databaseManager->getTableModel());
    dataMapper->addMapping(ui->debugLabel, databaseManager->getTableModel()->fieldIndex("item")); //ko
    QSqlQuery q;
    bool ret = q.exec("SELECT * FROM expense");

    if (!ret){
        databaseManager->showDebugMsg(q.lastError().text());
    }
    while (q.next()) {
        QString item = q.value(1).toString();
        databaseManager->showDebugMsg(item); //ok
    }

    dataMapper->toFirst();


}
```

Before I had populate the database with some test row and I'm sure it worked because

> databaseManager->showDebugMsg(item);

show me the right data. But the mapping fails. The getTableModel is pretty simple:

```
QSqlTableModel *  DatabaseManager::getTableModel(){
    tableModel->select();
    return tableModel;
}
```

and here it is the DatabaseManager constructor:

```
DatabaseManager::DatabaseManager(){
    debugMsgBox = new QMessageBox();
    this->deleteDB();
    this->openDB();
    this->createExpenseTable();
    this->insertTestExpense("test", 11.0);
    tableModel = new QSqlTableModel();
    tableModel->setTable("expense");

}
```

Since the insertTestExspense works, I think the problem may be in the setTable()... but I can't see what am I missing...

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things you can do to make it work:

1.Check if `fieldIndex("item")` actually returns a valid field index.

2.For the QLabel mapping also specify [text](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlabel.html#text-prop) property name for the datamanager's addMapping call:

```
dataMapper->addMapping(ui->debugLabel, databaseManager->getTableModel()>fieldIndex("item"), "text");
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: It worked. But why I need to specify the "text" parameter? The documentation is a little cryptic here http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdatawidgetmapper.html#addMapping-2 it says "adds the possibility to specify the property to use"... but property of which object?

Comment: addMapping allows to specify mapping between a widget and your model section. PropertyName parameter allows to define a property of a widget which should be used for mapping